# Closing a modal <dialog> element with a synthetic escape key

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am attempting to close a [modal `<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) by simulating an <kbd>escape</kbd> key press. I'll explain this example below:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  console.log(e)
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  console.log(e)
});
document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  console.log(e)
});

const dialog = document.querySelector(`dialog`);

const openDialogButton = document.querySelector(`#open-dialog-button`);
openDialogButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

const syntheticEscapeButton = document.querySelector(`#synthetic-escape-button`);
syntheticEscapeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      altKey: false,
      code: "Escape",
      ctrlKey: false,
      isComposing: false,
      key: "Escape",
      location: 0,
      metaKey: false,
      repeat: false,
      shiftKey: false,
      which: 27,
      charCode: 0,
      keyCode: 27,
    }));
  document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {
      altKey: false,
      code: "Escape",
      ctrlKey: false,
      isComposing: false,
      key: "Escape",
      location: 0,
      metaKey: false,
      repeat: false,
      shiftKey: false,
      which: 27,
      charCode: 0,
      keyCode: 27,
    }));
});

const closeDialogButton = document.querySelector(`#close-dialog-button`);
closeDialogButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```html
<input id="input-1" type="text">

<button id="open-dialog-button">Open Dialog</button>

<dialog>
  <div id="dialog-body">
    <p>Press the escape key to close the dialog box.</p>
    <input id="input-2" type="text">
    <button id="synthetic-escape-button">Press Synthetic Escape</button>
    <button id="close-dialog-button">Close Dialog</button>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

1. If you click the "Open Dialog" button then press the <kbd>escape</kbd> key, the dialog box **will** close.
2. If you click the "Open Dialog" button then click the "Press Synthetic Escape" button, the dialog box **will not** close.

Either way, the keyboard event listeners will fire. Why does the `<dialog>` close in #1 but not #2? How do I make a synthetic <kbd>escape</kbd> key close the `<dialog>` like #1?

---

For context, this is for an automated test I'm writing, but I'm looking for vanilla JS solutions. I'm using Firefox on Windows 10.

---

UPDATE: I just learned [the latest version (v3) of TestCafe uses native events](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode) by default, but only for certain browsers. Firefox is not one of them. By switching my test to use Google Chrome, I now automate an escape key as though a user pressed it.

I'm saying this for informative purposes only; I still want an answer to my original question. Hopefully this saves someone a lot of time in the future.

Comment: What test framework are you using? Cypress? If so, you might want to use `cy.type('{esc}')` or use a library like https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events

Comment: @Danziger Good question. I happen to be using testcafe. Originally, I was going to accept testcafe answers, but I decided it was worth knowing how to do this in vanilla JS. That way, I can learn why this isn't working; understanding that might help me understand future scenarios involving different elements.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog box closes in #1 (pressing the escape key) but not in #2 (synthetic escape button click) because there might be a ***difference in event dispatching***.

> 1. User interacts with the keyboard,
> 2. the browser receives the `keydown` event,
> 3. `keyup` event follows
> 4. triggers the default behavior of closing the dialog.

BUT, when you dispatch a *synthetic* event using document.dispatchEvent(), it ***does not trigger*** the defualt behavior for that event. The event listeners fire, but the dialog doesn't close because the default behavor is not executed.

To close the dialog using a synthetic escape key event, ***you can manually handle the event*** by just closing the dialog within your event listener for the escape key:

```
const syntheticEscapeButton = document.querySelector(`#synthetic-escape-button`);
syntheticEscapeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  handleEscapeKey(); // Call a custom function to handle the escape key event
});

function handleEscapeKey() {
  dialog.close(); // Manually close the dailog
}
```

By invoking the dialog.close() method directly within the event handler, you can *simulate the behavior of closing the dialog* with a synthetic escape key event, similar to scenario #1.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is, that's kind of what the `closeDialogButton` already does. I already have an automated test named, "When the user clicks the close button, the modal closes." I'm trying to implement a new one named, "When the user presses the escape key, the modal closes." To me it feels like directly calling `dialog.close();` wouldn't really be testing that.

Comment: By the way, any idea **why** `document.dispatchEvent()` doesn't trigger the default behavior of that event? Is this a weird edge case with `<dialog>` or are there myriad examples of synthetic events behaving differently from user events?

Comment: I tried looking into that, not sure what would cause that. Could be an edge case.

Comment: Oh and I want to elaborate on my first comment. The "When the user presses the escape key, the modal closes," test may sound excessive or it might sound like I'm testing the browser instead of *my* code, but I disagree: someday I may replace this `<dialog>` implementation to `<div>`s, and if that day comes, I want the escape key to work the same way.